# Running `airflow scheduler` launches 33 scheduler processes

Tags: python, airflow

When using `LocalExecutor` with a `MySQL` backend, running `airflow scheduler` on my Centos 6 box creates 33 scheduler processes, e.g.

`deploy   55362 13.5  1.8 574224 73272 ?        Sl   18:59   7:42 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
deploy   55372  0.0  1.5 567928 60552 ?        Sl   18:59   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
deploy   55373  0.0  1.5 567928 60540 ?        Sl   18:59   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
...`

These are distinct from Executor processes and gunicorn master and worker processes.
Running it with the `SequentialExecutor`  (`sqlite` backend) just kicks off one scheduler process.
Airflow still works (DAGs are getting run), but the sheer number of these processes makes me think something is wrong.
When I run `select * from job where state = 'running';` in the database, only 5 `SchedulerJob` rows get returned. 
Is this normal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes this is normal. These are scheduler processes. You can control this using below parameter in **airflow.cfg**

```
# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 32
```

These are spawned from scheduler whose pid can be found in **airflow-scheduler.pid** file

so 32+1=33 processes that you are seeing.

Hope this clears out your doubt.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Priyank!  You were absolutely right, changing the parallelism parameter changes the number of these `scheduler` processes.  I guess I'm confused, I thought parallelism referred to the executor processes that actually run the tasks.

Comment: @CollinMeyers they are the "executor" processes. They are just named "scheduler" in your PID list. If you start a scheduler for LocalExecutor, only 1 scheduler will run.

Answer (score 2):

As of v1.10.3, this is what I found. My settings are:

```
parallelism = 32
max_threads = 4
```

There are a total of

- 1 (main) +
- 32 (executors) +
- 1 (dag_processor_manager) +
- 4 (dag processors)

= 38 processes!

Comment: Hey, I hate those dag processors, they are not obeying `sql_alchemy_pool_size` . 
Can you tell me how to limit no of dag_processors ?

Comment: Yes, right now I've limited it to `max_threads = 1` . It is still unclear to me why in the name of thread processes are created, and if at all processes are created then why the same db connection pool is not shared across all the processes?