# Airflow sql alchemy pool size ignored

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, airflow

I am running airlfow local executor with a postgres database and I am getting a: `(psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved`

My configs:

`sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 1800
sql_alchemy_reconnect_timeout = 300`

Still I can see that airflow always keeps more connections open than the pool size.
[image: postgres - nr active connections]

How can we limit Airflow to **actually use** the pool limit?

*airflow_version = 1.10.2; postgres_version = 9.6*

Comment: Are you using SubDag Operators? Those do not honor the connection pool and can spawn tons of connections to Airflow DB. We had to rewrite our DAGs to eliminate them.

Comment: Nope, we are not using subdags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forks of the main process as workers, each of which manage their own thread pool.

Check the implementation of [LocalExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/executors/local_executor.html); as it is using multiprocessing under the hood. SqlAlchemy will close any open connections upon forking the `LocalWorker`; but the pool size will be equivalent to the parent, so at max, theoretically you'd have `k * (n + 1)` connections, where `n` is your parallelism constant and `k` is your `sql_alchemy_pool_size`.

Comment: To add to this, you also have SQL_ALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW which defines how many more connections can be spawned when the limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

People having the same problem with celery executor can try reducing scheduler.max_threads (AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MAX_THREADS) .

Theoretically `Max no connections from scheduler = (sql_alchemy_pool_size + sql_alchemy_max_overflow) x max_threads + 1[Dag processor Manager] + 1[Main scheduler process]`

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57411598/5860608 for further info.