# sql_alchemy_pool_size in Airflow couldn't be config

Tags: sqlalchemy, connection, airflow, pool

just testing airflow 2.4.2, python 3.10 and mysql 8.0.31

Has anyone seen any problems with sqlalchemy on this version?
I have the sql_alchemy_pool_size=5,sql_alchemy_max_overflow=10 configured but i can see much more connections on mysql when running dags / tasks.

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: I don't know a lot about airflow but this might be because these limits are per process.  If you spawn many processes then each process has potential for pool size + max_overflow of connections. Related [airflow-sql-alchemy-pool-size-ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121666/airflow-sql-alchemy-pool-size-ignored)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback
I'm not sure what is the Process here. 1 process = 1 task? I'm a newbie so I'm a bit confused