# Apache airflow run too many processes

Tags: airflow

I have all the following processes which are running with Airflow. I am trying to understand why there are so many with some duplicated and if they are all needed.
I am running a local executor with postgres and it run with `systemd` as explain by the following tutorial. https://towardsdatascience.com/an-apache-airflow-mvp-complete-guide-for-a-basic-production-installation-using-localexecutor-beb10e4886b2

I want to better understand the processes to debug it because it seems that the scheduler is not working currently. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
ubuntu   30932  0.0  0.0  76692   900 ?        Ss   00:53   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
ubuntu   30933  0.0  0.1 259528  2740 ?        S    00:53   0:00 (sd-pam)
root       525  0.0  0.3 107992  7280 ?        Ss   01:26   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv]
ubuntu     619  0.0  0.3 108228  6120 ?        S    01:26   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/0
ubuntu     626  0.0  0.2  23380  5388 pts/0    Ss+  01:26   0:00 -bash
root     19090  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    04:04   0:00 [kworker/u4:1]
root     15692  0.0  0.3 107992  7340 ?        Ss   04:44   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv]
ubuntu   15809  0.0  0.1 107992  3684 ?        S    04:44   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/1
ubuntu   15810  0.0  0.2  23380  5356 pts/1    Ss+  04:44   0:00 -bash
root     20272  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    04:50   0:00 [kworker/u4:0]
root     20274  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    04:50   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root     20676  0.0  0.3 107992  7416 ?        Ss   04:51   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv]
ubuntu   20783  0.0  0.3 108184  6200 ?        S    04:51   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/2
ubuntu   20784  0.0  0.2  23380  5376 pts/2    Ss   04:51   0:00 -bash
root     22974  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    04:54   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
ubuntu   23001  1.2  4.7 374404 95696 ?        Ss   04:54   0:04 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23002  2.2  6.2 501048 126200 ?       Ss   04:54   0:07 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow webserver
postgres 23030  0.0  0.8 321700 16512 ?        Ss   04:54   0:00 postgres: 10/main: airflow airflow ***.*.*.*(53558) idle
postgres 23031  0.1  0.9 322608 19976 ?        Ss   04:54   0:00 postgres: 10/main: airflow airflow ***.*.*.*(53560) idle
ubuntu   23038  0.6  4.2 1636692 84520 ?       Sl   04:54   0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23047  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    04:54   0:00 [/usr/bin/python] <defunct>
ubuntu   23048  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    04:54   0:00 [/usr/bin/python] <defunct>
ubuntu   23049  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    04:54   0:00 [/usr/bin/python] <defunct>
ubuntu   23052  0.0  3.9 372588 78492 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23053  0.0  3.9 372588 78492 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23056  0.0  3.9 372588 78492 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23058  0.0  3.9 372588 78428 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23059  0.0  3.9 372588 78428 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23063  0.0  3.9 372588 78436 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23064  0.0  3.9 372588 78436 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23069  0.0  3.9 372588 78440 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23072  0.0  3.9 372588 78440 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23074  0.0  3.9 372588 78440 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23077  0.0  3.9 372588 78440 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23080  0.0  3.9 372588 78440 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23082  0.0  3.9 372588 78440 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23086  0.0  3.9 372588 78440 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23089  0.0  3.9 372588 78444 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23091  0.0  3.9 372588 78444 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23093  0.0  3.9 372588 78448 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23097  0.0  3.9 372588 78448 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23099  0.0  3.9 372588 78448 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23103  0.0  3.9 372588 78448 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23104  0.0  3.9 372588 78448 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23108  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23112  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23113  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23117  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23118  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23122  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23125  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23128  0.0  3.9 372588 78452 ?        S    04:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
ubuntu   23142  1.3  4.1 373364 82908 ?        S    04:54   0:04 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
postgres 23179  0.0  0.9 322380 18120 ?        Ss   04:54   0:00 postgres: 10/main: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(53564) idle
ubuntu   23193  0.4  3.1 217464 63712 ?        S    04:54   0:01 gunicorn: master [airflow-webserver]
ubuntu   26167  1.3  5.9 494876 119428 ?       Sl   04:58   0:01 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
postgres 26181  0.0  0.8 321596 16640 ?        Ss   04:58   0:00 postgres: 10/main: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(54584) idle
ubuntu   26545  1.8  5.9 494876 119428 ?       Sl   04:58   0:01 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
postgres 26559  0.0  0.8 321596 16640 ?        Ss   04:58   0:00 postgres: 10/main: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(54714) idle
ubuntu   26910  3.6  5.9 494876 119428 ?       Sl   04:59   0:01 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
postgres 26924  0.0  0.8 321596 16640 ?        Ss   04:59   0:00 postgres: 10/main: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(54840) idle
ubuntu   27287 14.1  5.9 494876 119428 ?       Sl   04:59   0:01 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
postgres 27301  0.0  0.8 321596 16640 ?        Ss   04:59   0:00 postgres: 10/main: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(54966) idle
ubuntu   27411  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    05:00   0:00 [airflow schedul] <defunct>
ubuntu   27414  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    05:00   0:00 [airflow schedul] <defunct>
ubuntu   27423  0.0  0.1  40268  3884 pts/2    R+   05:00   0:00 ps -aux --sort start_time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of following question!

[Running `airflow scheduler` launches 33 scheduler processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729161/running-airflow-scheduler-launches-33-scheduler-processes)

Having theses many process is default behavior but you can change it  from `airflow.cfg` by changing `parallelism` value.